# List all foreign servers in all databases in current server with PL/pgsql dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, list

I'm trying to list ALL Foreign Servers in ALL databases on the server.

With information schema I can list all databases, but I haven't found an info schema that lists all FS's. The one that exists just lists for current database.

I can ONLY do this from PL/pgsql. So I was thinking of putting together a dynamic query, but it seems I cannot switch DB context in queries.

In TSQL, easy.

Is it not doable in PostgreSQL through a query, or am I missing something?

And yes, I know I can use DB_Link, but then I'd have to create a db link for every DB, not nice.

Comment: you don't "create" db links in Postgres. The dblink extensions provides a function to run an ad-hoc query on a different database without the need of any additional "create" statements (you also need that extension in only one database).

Comment: A Foreign Server to be used by a dblink.

Comment: The db link module does not use a foreign server. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html

Comment: We must be talking about two totally different things then because our entire infrastructure is based on making dblink calls with pre-defined foreign servers. Unless the client DB navigation app we use calls them Foreign Servers and they're actually some different name.

Comment: [Foreign Servers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html)  is a completely different concept than [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  They are not **completely** different, you can use a foreign server name as the connection name for a dblink call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with in case anyone finds it useful:

```
do
$$
declare link_arr text[];
declare tmp_arr text[];
declare cmd text;
declare db_arr text[];
declare d text;
begin
db_arr = array(SELECT array_agg(distinct datname) FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false);
foreach d in array db_arr
loop
    if d= 'rdsadmin' then continue; end if;
    cmd = format($cmd$select array_agg((db, link)) from dblink('dbname=%s user=me password=pass', 'select foreign_server_catalog as db, foreign_server_name as link from information_schema.foreign_servers;') as t(db text,link text)$cmd$, d);

    execute cmd into tmp_arr;
    if tmp_arr is null then continue; end if; 

    link_arr = (select array_cat(link_arr, tmp_arr));
end loop;

raise INFO '%', link_arr;

end
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

The catalog table defining foreign servers is not a shared catalog, it exists separately in each database.  You will have to connect to each database in turn to get this information.  How TSQL does things won't help you much in getting things done in PostgreSQL.